# GPL source code, Interacting with proprietary software using socket, is it a GPL violation?

Tags: gpl, gpl-2

I have a open source application (written in PHP), Which depends on daemon/service process to do certain tasks. This open source application communicates with daemon/service process using socket.

Should I open source the daemon/service process also ?

Comment: What sort of communications take place over that socket?

Comment: @MadHatter, thanks for your response. In socket, I send some command and params to do a certain task, Which cant be done by the PHP application. Certain tasks needs some special permission, some special workloads, which are getting done by daemon process.

Comment: Is it something that, *ceteris paribus*, could be done equally well by a simple fork-and-exec call into userspace, possibly using `sudo` to acquire the privilege required?  If not, it would be helpful to understand why not.  Please note that I'm not suggesting you need to do it that way, it's just helpful to understand if you're achieving the exact equivalent of *sudo-fork-and-exec* via other means.

Comment: See also [GPL FAQ - When is a program and its plug-ins considered a single combined program?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLPlugins)

Comment: @Brandin That's not really helpful since that's just their opinion and doesn't seem to have any basis in law. In fact, the notion of a "single combined program" doesn't really seem to have any basis in law so far as I know. The legal test is whether one work, at rest, contains sufficient protectable expression taken from the other, at rest.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz All comments and answers on this site are opinions as well and don't have any basis in law, unless you can provide a legal citation for some kind of relevant case. I.e. your opinion is just yet one more opinion.

Comment: @Brandin I certainly can provide several citations. I wonder if they can. It's just not particularly relevant to this question. (Punch "sufficient protectable expression" into your favorite search engine and you'll find many of them. While "single combined program" won't get you much. One is an actual legal concept under US law, the other isn't.)

Comment: Thank God the US legal system is applicable the world over, so answers need take only it, and no other regulatory regime, into account.

Comment: @MadHatter You only need to take other regimes into account when you have some reason to think those other regimes are different with respect to the particular subject under discussion. Do you have some reason to think that?

Answer (score 2):

We can't answer with just what you've told us. That the two pieces of software interoperate over a socket is irrelevant. What matters is whether the software you are trying to decide whether you must open source contains sufficient protectable expression taken from the open source application. That they communicate over a socket tells us nothing about what elements of the open source program are or are not in the service process.

If they only communicate over a socket and no protectable expression that came from the open source project appears in the daemon/service process, then there is no requirement that you open source the deamon/service process.